# Getting user info while using ux_mode :'redirect' for google sign-in using custom image

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-signin

I want to use **ux_mode:redirect** instead of the default **popup** method for google sign-in with javascript. Currently the login takes place as below,

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadGoogleCallback" async defer></script>


<script>
function onLoadGoogleCallback(){

   element = document.getElementById('glogin');

   //console.log(element);

    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
         scope: 'profile',
        //ux_mode : 'redirect'
      });

     auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
       function(googleUser) {
           console.log('Signed in: ' + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
           var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
           console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
           console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
           console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
         }, 
         function(error) {
           console.log('Sign-in error', error);
         }
       );
    });



}
</script>
```

where **glogin** is the id of my img for google sign-in.

```
<img src="./img/login-g.jpg" id="glogin" >
```

This is working fine and i am getting info in the console. But if i try the redirect method,nothing is shown in the console. What do i use instead of  **auth2.attachClickHandler(...)** to get the info after login?

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?

Comment: @BozhinovskiVladimir, No, used the default popup method.

Comment: What I found out is when you are on local development environment when you on redirect login you are losing the state because of the google HTTPS